# Animating Filters in iOS

Tags: ios, image, filter

How would i implement an animation of a filter in iOS apps.
E.g. i have a still image with an applied Blur Filter. Then the image animates to the sharp/normal version. I know of some good frameworks for Image processing like this one. Also i am aware of CoreImage with integrated filters. But i cant find a way of a smooth animation of the filter values.

The next question i: If there is a way to animate them, can the animation be stopped by the tap of a button?

thanks folks,
masiar

Answer (score 0):

take a copy of the original image,  apply filter to it, set its opacity to 0,  keep it over the orginal image,  use UIViewAnimation to set its opacity to 1.
after all that is done, replace the original image with the new one and remove the new image from uiview,
  ask me if you couldnt get what i am saying, or if u need further help